Match type: Irrefutable pattern is allowed only for the last case statement
I was trying to use the syntax match with a generic, but it wasn't working so I tried match type().
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

class LetterList(BaseModel):
    letter: str

class NumberList(BaseModel):
    numbers: list[int]

class BulletPointsList(BaseModel):
    bullet: str


ListType = LetterList | NumberList | BulletPointsList | None

T = TypeVar("T", bound=ListType)

class ListPattern(Generic[T]):

    def test(self, list_type: T, other_list_type: ListType):
        match other_list_type:
            case T(): # "Unbound" is not a class
                pass
            case BulletPointsList():
                pass
            case _:
                pass

    def test2(self, list_type: T, other_list_type: ListType):
        match type(other_list_type): 
            case T: # Irrefutable pattern is allowed only for the last case statement
                pass
            case BulletPointsList: # Irrefutable pattern is allowed only for the last case statement
                pass
            case _:
                pass

    def test3(self, list_type: T, other_list_type: ListType):
        # nicer way to write this?
        if type(list_type) == type(other_list_type):
            pass
        elif type(other_list_type) == BulletPointsList:
            pass
        else:
            pass

I am confused by why matching a type is an irrefutable pattern, when the following works:
a = 3
match a:
    case 1: # a == 1, similar to type(other_list_type) == BulletPointsList ?
        print("hi")
    case 2:
        print("hello")
    case _:
        print("_")


It seems to have to do with dots. answer
import builtins
from typing import Any


class ListPattern(Generic[T]):

    def test(self, other_list_type: Any):
        match type(other_list_type): 
            case builtins.str:
                print("str")
            case _:
                print("other")

ListPattern().test(
    other_list_type=""
)

Can this be done with our own types?
Edit:
"BulletPointsList" is not accessedPylance
Irrefutable pattern is allowed only for the last case statementPylance
(variable) BulletPointsList: type[LetterList] | type[NumberList] | type[BulletPointsList] | type[None]

It seems to think that BulletPointsList is a variable.

I suspect you meant case list_type:.  T matches all three list types, which is why it is irrefutable, but I think you were trying to say "if other_list_type matches the type of list_type".  Python is not C++; it doesn't do deep type inference.

@TimRoberts I want do something like pattern = ListPattern[LetterList] for one of the list types, and then other_list_type can be any of the list types. Since other_list_type has many possibilities, I do the matching on it. (However, ListPattern[ListType] is indeed allowed, which isn't ideal. BulletPointsList alone also causes an irrefutable pattern)
